# Image not shown after selecting from a menu with many items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script which shows a menu.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   m_route_lijst_width = '90%';
   function toon_menu (id) {
     //alert (document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight);
     if (document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight > 45) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.height = '22px';  
        document.getElementById(id).style.width = '22px';
        document.getElementById(id).style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('copyright').style.visibility = 'hidden';
     } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.height = '80%';   
        document.getElementById(id).style.width = m_route_lijst_width;      
        document.getElementById(id).style.overflow = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('copyright').style.visibility = 'visible';}
     } // function
</script>
```

At first the menu is small with only a little image in it. (below the coloured buttons)
When clicked on that image there is a bigger menu shown with the items to be selected (gpx-files)

If an item is selected this items will be shown on a map (with the leaflet script) and the menu will be small again with the small image in it again.
Using:

```
<div onclick="toon_menu('route_lijst');">
  <h2>
    <img src="img/wandelaar.png" alt="Klik op de knop om alle routes te tonen of om ze weer te verbergen" title="Klik op de knop om alle routes te tonen of om ze weer te verbergen" name="route_lijst_icon" id="route_lijst_icon" width="22" height="22" border="0">
    <span id="route_lijst_titel" class="route_lijst_titel">Wandelroutes</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

When the big menu has many items and therefore scroll-bars at the rightside and you select an item at the bottom, the menu still becomes small again but not the wanted image is shown.

Instead of the image there is some text of one of the items.

On the index page it works as supposed, selecting an item shows the route on a map and on the left is a small button with a pedestrian image in it.

On the bicyle's page it's not working as supposed - selecting the small pedestrian shows the full menu but when I select an item at the bottom (after scrolling down) there is no small pedestrian at the left but some text of an item from the menu.
Selecting an item at the top of the list however is working fine.

How do I force my menu to show the image instead of the text?

On my testing page you can see what I mean.

http://westera0.home.xs4all.nl/

My css file looks like this

The part .route_lijst is the part when the menu is fully shown

```
body {
   font: 12px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px; 
}

.map {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px; 
}

.soort_route {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 55px;
   width: 550px;
   height: 44px;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 7px #999;
   background: #ceeca8;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 8px;
   z-index: 100; 
}

.route_lijst {
   position: absolute;
   top: 85px;
   left: 55px;
   width: 22px;
   height: 22px;    
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 7px #999;
   background: #f8f8f9;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 8px;
   z-index:100; 
}

.route_lijst h2 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0; 
}

.route_info {
   margin: 2px;
   padding: 6px;
   background-color:#eee;
   width: 265px;
   float: left;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px; 
}

.route_knop {
   display: inline-block;
   width:100%;
   height:100%; 
}

.route_lijst_titel {
   vertical-align: top; 
}
```